# When working with css animations, is there is any way to make successive animations repeat infinitely in the given order

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

When I was working with CSS animations, I had to make two animations successive, but as soon as I did that, I just remembered that the animations must repeat infinitely. Is there is any way to make them repeat infinitely in the same order without making the animations one by merging keyframes, using only CSS?

If there isn't, how could I do it with JavaScript?

I tried re-invoking the animation in the last keyframe of the last animation but that didn't work because you can't animate animation.

```
.div{

animation: spin 1.6s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal running,
           rotate 1s ease-in-out 1.5s 1 normal running;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    animation: spin 1.6s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal running,
               rotate 1s ease-in-out 1.5s 1 normal running;
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotatez(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotatez(-33deg) rotatey(-37deg);

      ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new animation based on your requirements:

```css
.box{
 background:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
animation: spin 2.6s ease-in-out  infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  61.54% { /*1.6s */
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotatez(0) rotatey(0) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotatez(-33deg) rotatey(-37deg) translateZ(1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the animations must be successive and they can't overlap, while we can use a negative delay in the example I give to make them overlap, I know it can be done using the way you're giving but it will require some predictions and it probably not gonna work with an ease ou timing function for example.

Comment: @YassineSafraoui you cannot have overlap since your animation the same property

Comment: I'm animating the rotatez and y and x, are they the same?!

Comment: @YassineSafraoui you are not animating rotate. You are animating *transform* and transform is the same so you cannot animate the same property differently.